# How to load an image to an applet?

Tags: java, image, applet

I want to load an image to an applet but I keep getting a nullpointerexception whenever I run my program. Here is the code I am using to load the image. Please help.

```
img = getImage(getDocumentBase(), getParameter("questionmark2.jpg"));
g.drawImage(img, 100, 100, this);
```

Comment: Could you please add the code for functions `getImage`. `getDocumentBase` and `getParameters`?

Comment: Where is the image located?

Comment: @CrApHeR [`getImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getImage(java.net.URL)), [`getDocumentBase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getDocumentBase()), [`getParameter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getParameter(java.lang.String))

Comment: The image is located on my computer.

Comment: Is the image located at the same directory?

Comment: It is located in the same directory as the .java file.

Comment: try putting img = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "questionmark2.jpg");

Comment: Or use `BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/class package name/questionmark2.jpg");`, where `class package name` is the class package separated by `/` instead of `.`

Comment: Ivan thanks for your help but I already tried that. Madprogrammer, can you please explain what you mean by class package.

Comment: Is it really `questionmark2.jpg` as opposed to `QuestionMark2.jpg` or `questionmark2.JPG` etc.?  *"It is located in the same directory as the .java file."*  The document base refers to the location of the **HTML**, not the class or the `.java` file.  Is the image in the same location as the **HTML?**  But why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: I found a different way to do it but thanks for your help! And yes my teacher forced me to code an applet. I keep telling him applets are not proper but he is stubborn!

Comment: Duplicate of [What is a `NullPointerException` and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it?s=1|2.9102)